# How to export the list of username and computername that is incorrect or not avaialble in AD from the below script?

Tags: powershell

How can this script below modified to export the list of the both **servers.txt** and **Accounts.txt** that is not available in Active Directory?

The below script is working fine to import the lists from both files that are available and online, but I need to get the list of wrong or unavailable accounts & computer name into separate log files like:

failed_username.log and failed_computername.log respectively.

```
$Servers = Get-Content "C:\Users\$env:username\desktop\servers.txt" | Where-Object { ((Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$($_)'" -Properties OperatingSystem).OperatingSystem -like '*Windows Server*') -and (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 2 -Quiet) }
$Users = Get-Content "C:\Users\$env:username\desktop\Accounts.txt" | Where-Object { (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($_)'") }

ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
{
    $ComputerName = $Server.Trim()
    Write-Host "Processing $ComputerName" -ForegroundColor Green
    ForEach ($Username in $Users)
    {
        $UserName = $User.Trim()
        Write-Host "Processing $UserName" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest another approach? I think it wouldn't make that much sense to put users and computers to the same list.

I'd do it this way: I'd collect the information about the computers in a list like this:

```
$ServerInputList = 
Get-Content "C:\Users\$env:username\desktop\servers.txt" 

foreach ($ComputerName in $ServerInputList) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name   = $ComputerName
        OS     = (Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$($ComputerName)'" -Properties OperatingSystem).OperatingSystem
        Online = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet
    }
}
```

Now you can easily filter for the computers you want.
The same would work for the users.